# Intercept Session Start event for all applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have an IIS server (7.5) that hosts several applications each of them run in their own application pool identity.  I am trying to write some code that intercepts the Session On Start event.  I have successfully written other IHttpModules that are processed for all requests but, in this case I only want to intercept the first time the session is initiated.  I want to do this for all the web applications at a global level within my web site.  My plan is to use this to capture the last logon date for the user on a per web app basis to satisify an auditing requirement.

I have all the pieces in place except the event that I need to intercept.  It seems all IHttpModule Events fire on all requests.  I figured the Session_Start event would be ideal but it doesn't look like I can tie into this from an IHttpModule.

I looked at the SessionStateUtility but I do not want to rewrite session functionality, I just want to intercept the start event.

Is there another interface out there I can use to intercept Session_Start?  Any other recommendations?

Comment: What does it mean by "first time the session is initiated."?

Comment: I want to tie into an event that first the first time a users accesses an application.  Similar to the Session_Start but, from a Module level not in the application itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        var sessionModule = context.Modules["Session"] as SessionStateModule;
        if (sessionModule != null)
        {
            sessionModule.Start += this.Session_Start;
        }
    }
    private void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do whatever you want to do here.
    }
```

Comment: I just tried a quick prototype and this looks like it worked, can't believe I missed that event earlier.  Thanks!